# Symfony2 Guard not saving session

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, session

Symfony 3.0.2

My config (everything else is near default):

```
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
    save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    cookie_httponly: false
```

security:

```
security:
    encoders:
        XXX\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:          ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MODERATOR:     ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:         ROLE_MODERATOR
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        xx_userbundle:
            id: xx.user_provider

    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern: ^/report/(footer|report)
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~

            guard:
                provider: xx_userbundle
                authenticators:
                    - xx.user_authenticator

            logout:
                path: /auth/logout

            remember_me:
                name: vsess
                secret: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /
                remember_me_parameter: remember_me

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/auth, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_MODERATOR }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I'm using guard functionality to allow auth using json content from angular. 
`UserAuthenticator` class is near default with the only exception to `onAuthenticationSuccess` which is like this:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$providerKey.'.target_path');

    if (!$targetPath) {
        $targetPath = $this->getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl();
    }
    $jsonRequest = $request->getContentType() == 'json';

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $jsonRequest) {
        $data = array(
            'success' => true,
            'redirect' => $targetPath
        );

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    } else {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and dandy EXCEPT saving session to file, session dir is empty. Although when i check `Request` session id is there. When i check login route in profiler i see this:

```
security    Guard authenticator set success response.
Context: { "response": "Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse)", "authenticator": "XXX\\UserBundle\\Security\\UserAuthenticator" }
security    Clearing remember-me cookie.
Context: { "name": "vsess" }
security    Did not send remember-me cookie.
Context: { "parameter": "remember_me" }
security    Remember-me was not requested.
security    The "XXX\UserBundle\Security\UserAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called
security    Stored the security token in the session.
Context: { "key": "_security_main" }
```

BUT, set-cookie in request is empty:

```
set-cookie  vsess=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

Is there any reason why it is not working? Should i save session or cookie myself? I bet there is some kind of misconfiguration problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Having the sameproblem in 2018 with Symfony 4.2